# C# When using modulus (%) operator, how do one take care of remaining values after the last N'th value?

Tags: c#, for-loop, modulo

I am new in C# and decided to use the modulo operator.

I have a case where im using a foreach loop to go through a collection of 5300 items.

I am using the modulo operator to do something every 1000th item.

Something like:

`if(i % 1000 = 0)
{
    //Do something
}`

I am hitting the if statement every 1000th but did not consider the last 300 items, which i also need to take into account.

The purpose is to loop through the last 300, if there is any, after i hit the last 1000th item.

Thanks!

Comment: `300 % 1000` surely returns 300, not zero, so the condition surely will never be true. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Handle the 1000th element of your collection and all the rest? Or only every 1000th element plus the very last element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
if( i % 1000 == 0 || 5300 - i < 1000)
```

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Good job.

Comment: Oh yes, this is integer division, good point, this will pass if it is 4301 or over currently, it should be reverted, very sorry!